# Debug & analyze pthread_mutex_lock issues

Tags: strace, gdb, lock

I've being recently facing some hardcore issues with Mutex lock for Linux, notably MySQL, memcache & APCu.

Example:

- SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO
- APCu: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/416
- Memcache OOM: out of memory related stuff

My understanding of Linux is very very basic & limited. I get that mutex is a mechanism which ensures that two or more concurrent processes don't collide or cause a race condition, which is all fine by me.

- For the MySQL case, I knew MySQL had a lock on some InnoDB table, so a restart did solve the problem. But what I didn't get is what process got killed while holding that lock. Who killed it and for what reason, and what was the code triggering that scenario? I'm using MySQL 8, and I figured I could check performance_schema.data_lock_waits maybe? But what step to take after that?
- For APCu: I did run strace on the running PHP process, got a FUTEX_WAIT, did run a GDB and got apcu_inc stucks on pthread_rwlock_wrlock. Disabling APCu did solve the problem, as upgrading did too. This was a chance to investigate this further, but couldn't since I had to quickly solve this on a prod server. I can reproduce it. There are so many software packages out there that use APCu, and if not, a lot uses pthread_mutex_lock, so I can't go around uninstalling anything related to that.
- For memcached: it keeps crashing again & again; we're using a very old version (2012 stuff). Looking at the releases notes, I do understand that memcache is having some difficulties with this. I'm planning to look at the different issues related to get and overview and if there is anything that can help me investigate this further. I can't go around opening issues like "hey I have OOM". I need to do my part of job, at least share some stuff or be able to reproduce.

I get two situations from this:

- Running process: I think I can manage this one, digging in the code and looking around, hoping someone else encountered this.
- Killed process: I don't know how to deal with this one. In the case of MySQL and Memcache, who killed them and for what reason? Can I trace the code, do I need some tool to monitor these? How to figure out what happened? Do I need to look at some device lock or I/O?

How do you approach this?